# Best way to calculate how many additional individuals would be needed to sample 100% of asymptotic species richness of a sample/region - iNEXT?

Tags: inext

I am starting to use SPADE and iNEXT R packages. I think I have finally got my head around most of what I need so far but...

Chao et al, (2009) present an Excel calculator to calculate how many additional individuals would be needed to sample 100% of asymptotic species richness of a sample/region (G=1 in the paper, link below):

http://viceroy.eeb.uconn.edu/Colwell/RKCPublications/ChaoColwellLinGotelli2009.pdf

My question is, can this be achieved in iNEXT, or even EstimateS, and if so, how?

Basically, I want to calculate how many additional samples I would require to reach 80%, 90%, 95%, 99% and 100% sample completeness.

I don't really want to do 95% of the work in iNEXT or EstimateS, but then have to calculate one number separately!

Thank you in advance!